# Can't run rm command in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, rm

Good Day,

I am trying to run a build file to remove files in sublime text 2. Like this:

```
"cmd": ["make","all"],
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.makefile",
"path": "/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Raaj/sat/bin",

"variants":
 [
   {
     "name": "Clean",
     "cmd": ["rm", "-f","demo.hex","demo.elf"]
   },
   {
     "name": "All",
     "cmd": ["make", "all"]
   }
 ]
}
```

All works great, however upon clean, it says

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'rm', u'-f', u'demo.hex', u'demo.elf']]
[dir:  /Users/Raaj/Documents/STM32F4/Project/IO_Toggle]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Raaj/sat/bin]
[Finished]
```

Even if i changed rm to some rubbish like lol. it gives the same error. I dont get it

Comment: It looks like you are on Mac.  When I do `which rm`, I get `/bin/rm`, meaning `rm` is in the `/bin` folder.  This folder is not in the path you are telling Sublime text to search in.  Add `/bin` to the "path" variable.

Comment: thx! any idea where TELNET is located on mac?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but there is a closing bracer with no open bracer to match?

Comment: yes it was, do you know where TELNET is located on the mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic commands like `rm` and `ls` are usually located in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.  You need to add these paths to the "path" variable so Sublime Text 2 can find them.

```
"path": "/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Raaj/sat/bin:/bin:/usr/bin",
```

If you need to locate where a program lives, use the `which` command:

```
$ which telnet
/usr/bin/telnet
```

Comment: It's in `/usr/bin`, which is part of this answer.

Comment: what if i wanted to run a command inside an app. Say i telnet into a program. then inside that program, i want to run commands. can i do this in sublime

Comment: @user1436508 That should be asked as a separate question, since it is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @user1436508 Also, I don't know how to do that.  I hear it's a limitation with Sublime Text 2 that you can't do that, but I'm not sure.